# Python: Revealing a word for Hangman (Strings, replace, index, and strip)

Tags: python, replace, indexing, find, strip

lets say I have the word: "Pizza"

```
sAnswer = "Pizza"
sReveal = len(sAnswer)* "_ "
```

Above I've built a string that'd display "_ _ _ _ _ "

Like any other Hangman game it would contain underscores my problem is: How do I strip the sReveal of spaces, find the index of the letter guessed (example: 'z') and then replace the underscores with z's where necessary and then rebuild the spaces in between, therefore it would become: "_ _ z z _ "

I've tried something like this to no avail:

```
if sLetterGuessed in list(sAnswer):

    for character in list(sAnswer): 
        index = sAnswer.find(sLetterGuessed)
        sReveal = sReveal.replace(" ", "")
        list(sReveal)[index] = "z"

        print sReveal

        for char in sReveal:
            sReveal = sReveal.strip(" ")
            sReveal = sReveal.replace("_", char) 

    print sReveal
    print HangingMan[iErrors]

## The code is just consideration of the route I'm taking with this; the horrible route.
```

Comment: Try this: `' '.join("P____")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to update sReveal is use a list comp and `str.join`:

```
sAnswer = "Pizza"
sReveal = len(sAnswer)* "_ " 
letter_guessed = "z"
# if letter_guessed == current letter in word, add that letter else add a _
sReveal = " ".join([x if x==letter_guessed else "_" for x in sAnswer ])
print(sReveal)
_ _ z z _
```

An old hangman game I had to do for a course might be useful:

```
def hangman(secret_word):
    from string import ascii_lowercase
    print ("Welcome to Hangman!")
    print ("I am thinking of a word that is {} letters long\n-----------".format(len(secret_word)))
    guesses = 8
    letters_guessed = []
    missed_l = ''
    correct_l = ''
    secret_word = secret_word.lower()
    while True:
        # if all the letters in secret_word are in correct_l , the user has won 
        if all(x in correct_l for x in secret_word):
            print ("Congratulations, you won!")
            break
        # if len missed letters is 8, user has used up all guesses so break/end teh game
        elif len(missed_l) == 8:
            print ("Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was {}.".format(secret_word))
            break
        print ("You have {} guesses left".format(guesses))
        print ("Available Letters: {}".format(" ".join([x for x in ascii_lowercase if x not in letters_guessed])))
        guess = raw_input("Please guess a letter: ").lower()
        # if guess in letters_guessed  user has already guessed that letter
        if guess in letters_guessed:
            print ("Sorry You've already guessed that letter: {}\n-----------".format(guess))
        # else if it is in the word, add  guess to correct_l and to letters guessed 
        elif guess in secret_word:
            letters_guessed.append(guess)
            correct_l += guess
            print("Good guess: {}\n-----------".format(" ".join([x if x in letters_guessed else "_" for x in secret_word])))
        # if users guess is not in the word, minus a  life/guess
        elif guess not in secret_word:
            letters_guessed.append(guess)
            guesses -= 1
            print (" That letter is not in my word: {}\n-----------".format(" ".join([x if x in letters_guessed else "_" for x in secret_word])))
            missed_l += guess
```

Comment: Your code works but sReveal resets itself (inside a while loop) And doesn't keep it's value after ever guessed entry.
I'd like to keep  " _ _ z z _ "
then allow the player to guess again "a" so then the next sReveal will be "_ _ z z a "

Comment: @42Cosmic, you need to keep track of all letters guessed outside the loop then you just need that single line of code to update sReveal.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting sReveal to a list, but you're not saving the list, so it has no effect after all.

Try this:

```
aReveal = list(sReveal)

index = sAnswer.find(sLetterGuessed)
while index >= 0:
    aReveal[index] = sLetterGuessed
    index = sAnswer.find(sLetterGuessed, index + 1)

sReveal = ''.join(aReveal)
print sReveal
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "saving the list" and how do you do it? sReveal = ''.join(aReveal)

Comment: I meant this line:
    list(sReveal)[index] = "z".

You create a list using sReveal, but you're not assigning the list to a variable. And creating a list based on sReveal doesn't actually modify sReveal in any way. This is why when you print sReveal in the next line, it will just print the original string.

Notice in my code, I assign the list to aReveal, make changes, and then assign it back to sReveal.